# Sum of balls of convex set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $V$ be an Euclidean space, with a non-empty convex set $Z$. Let $r>0$. Prove that the set $\cup_{x \in Z} \ \ B(x,r) \supset Z$ is also convex in $V$.

There are plenty of proofs when I have a sum of finite (or $\mathbb{N} $ elements) but I can't find any hints on how to tackle this problem.
Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick two points $u,v$ in the set $K = \cup_{x\in Z} B(x,r)$ and $x,y\in Z$ such that
$$
\|u-x\|<r, \|v-y\| < r
$$
Now if $0<t<1$, let $z:= tx+(1-t)y \in Z$, then
$$
\|tu+(1-t)v - z\| \leq t\|u-x\| + (1-t)\|v-y\| < r
$$
So $tu+(1-t)v \in K$ as well.